# Version files locally with Tortoise SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I'm new to use CI and source control in general.  I'm working on a project where I've checked out a working copy of the repository onto my hard drive.  I find that as I'm working with a particular file, I'll periodically break/fix things.  I'd like to get something working, commit that change so I know at least some functionality is working, so when I break something the next time I don't have to start from scratch again and wonder where the breakage occurred.  Does Tortoise SVN work by when I click on SVN Commit that it commits changes to the repository that everyone is using?  If so, is it typically a problem to have tons of commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when you commit in SVN it is committing the change to the central repository (the one that your other team members are using).

It is not typically a problem to have a ton of commits.  Normally, "problems" in SVN arise when you have a bunch of people working on the same set of files; the merges can tend to become complicated.

If you are looking for the ability to version your changes locally and only push your changes out when they are ready you want to be using a distributed version control system like git or mercurial.

Comment: So the typically plan of attack is to get something working locally, commit it, and then work on the next piece of functionality and when that works, commit it, etc.  No reason to keep local versioned copies of files?

Comment: I typically try to commit early and often.  As soon as I have a piece of functionality working; I commit it.

Comment: that's what I was thinking.  Thanks :)

Comment: I think normally, when committing to trunk, you want to make sure it at least COMPILES before you commit. If you're committing to a private or feature branch, then pretty much anything goes.